# How to clear memory in map if it contains pointer?

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures

Consider

`map <char,node*> mp;` 
     where node is a class

If we use `mp.clear();` then is it required to free the memory explicitly?

Comment: Is this managed c++ or not? Assuming it is not, then the answer is yes. Unless those pointers are owned by some other class that will eventually release them.

Comment: `mp.clear()` will *destruct* (not `delete`) the values - destructing a pointer basically does nothing. Either store a `node` directly (not a pointer), or use a [**smart pointer**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), such as [`unique_ptr<node>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), which manages the memory cleanup for you.

Comment: How do you "clear memory" if you have a pointer? Do all pointers point to memory that has to be "cleared"?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that a raw pointer conveys no information about ownership, i.e. who is responsible for cleaning up the nodes. Is this map the owner of the nodes? Then you need to delete the objects. Or far better, you use `unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers. But if the map is not the owner of the nodes, then you must not delete the nodes.

The bottom line is to understand the concept of ownership and use an appropriate smart pointer.